# Javascript Dynamic Arrays and Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

**Is this possible?**

So I need to have an array with a dynamic name and content what can be extended and accessed.

```
object = {};
var two = ['thing', 'thing2'];
for(one in two){
    object[two[one]] = [];
}
```

If yes but not in this way, then how?

Comment: Eh?  I'm not sure what you're asking.  Also, iterating an `Array` with `for-in` is considered bad practice; use a C-style `for` loop or use `Array.prototype.forEach` if available.

Comment: Sorry, it's really hard to explain for me :\

Comment: Note that the code sample you show there declares a global `one` variable, unless you have `var one` elsewhere in your function. Best practice for iterating properties of an object is `for (var prop in obj){ if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){ ... } }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely doable, just make sure that the object owns the property and it's not inherited from higher up in the prototype chain:

```
object = {};
var two = ['thing', 'thing2'];
```

`for..in`:

```
for(var one in two){
    if(two.hasOwnProperty(one))
       object[two[one]] = [];
}
```

`for`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < two.length; i++)
   object[two[i]] = [];
```

Comment: You are missing a `var` on one, causing it to be globally defined (and potentially collide).

Comment: @Phrogz, Oops. Missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var object = {};
var props  = 'thing thing2'.split(' ');
for (var i=0,len=props.length;i<len;++i){
  object[props[i]] = [];
}
```